# Firebase nested loop wait for completion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have nested loop, something similar to this:

```
...
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

         ...
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             writeMessage("hello");
         }
         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         }

     }


     writeMessage("bye");


}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
```

I want the for loop to finish and print "hello" 5 times (for example) and only then! continue and print "bye" message.
I tried to search for similar topics but couldn't find any answer on how to implement it, hope you could help me.

Thanks

Comment: obviously something similar to this: inside onDataChange if counter == 5(for example) then writeMessage("bye");

Comment: Dont see really a nested loop though, I see one loop. And probably before the ```onDataChange``` You asign a listener? So that is only being called when the data actually changes. So either move ```writeMessage("hello");``` outside the ```onDataChange``` method or show some more code

Comment: Selvin's approach is likely to be what you want. But aside from that: it'll be hard to give you useful code as an answer, unless you actually post a real [minimal reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now, there is no way to understand how the inner `onDataChange()` and the outer `onDataChange()` are related (so how to determine the exit criteria for the loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is each `DataSnapshot` run on a single thread, for example: if `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` equals 5 then the nested loop you created will generate 6 threads: one for the outer `onDataChange()` and the other for 5 inner `onDataChange()`. So, if you want to print "bye" at last line, you should sync for counting inner `onDataChange()`. The below code is not tested yet.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     count = 0;
     final int target = number_of_children_in_dataSnapshot;
     for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

         ...
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             writeMessage("hello", target);
         }
         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         }

     }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}

Integer count = 0;
private synchronized void writeMessage(String message, int target) {
    count++;
    if (count == target) {
        // do write bye
        return;
    }
    // do write message
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I hope in the future firebase will give us the option to track query completion